# How can I login as admin after redirect to custom login page

Tags: login, buddypress, wp-redirect

I have created a dynamic link button that links to Buddypress user profile. A login user that clicks on this button will be brought to user's profile. However, a guest that clicks on this button will be by default redirected to WP login page. I want a user to be redirected to my custom login page. How can I do that?

I've tried this code. It works. It redirects to my custom login page. But how can I login to WP as admin in order to go to admin dashboard? As I go to `wp-login.php`, it will redirect me to my custom page in stead.

```
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');

function possibly_redirect(){
    global $pagenow;
    if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
        wp_redirect('http://localhost/test/login/');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you login as admin in your custom login page?

Comment: I can login via custom login page with my admin account  but I cannot go to admin dashboard. When  go to wp-admin, I will be redirected to wp default login page. I have asked the author of the plugin of the custom login page and he said that it's separated. I cannot go to admin dashboard directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to redirect the logged-in users. So I would recommend that you add another conditional and redirect the users only if they are not logged in:

```
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');
function possibly_redirect(){
    global $pagenow;
    if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow && ! is_user_logged_in()) {
        wp_redirect('http://localhost/test/login/');
        exit();
    }
}
```

This way you won't be redirected after login.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but nothing changes, still same.

Comment: If I login with my admin account via my custom login page, I cannot go to wp-admin. If I type in wp-admin at the end of the url, I will be brought to wp-login page to login again. So if I use the code  above that I show you, it will replace wp-login.php with my custom login page. As a result, if I type wp-login.php at the end of the url, I will be brought to my cusom login page. My question is how can I login to wp admin dashboard. I hope you get my meaning.

Comment: For other plugins, I can find the file to edit to change to my custom login page link. For example, this text...."You must login to post a comment" By default if I click on  the word login in the quotation, I will be brought to default wp login page. But I can change the path as the know where to edit the file. But for Buddypress I don't know where to edit the file.